# React async fetch with 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch 20 random users data from 'https://randomuser.me/api' and in some cases, I get the 503 Service Unavailable error.

I tried to resolve the problem with this kind of code:

```
async function fetchDriver() {
    const driver = await fetch(driverUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json();
            }
            if (response.status === 503) {
                return fetchDriver();
            }
        })
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            fetchDriver();
        });
    return driver;
}

do {
    const geoPosition = fetchGeoPosition();
    const phoneNumber = fetchPhoneNumber();
    const licenseNumber = fetchLicense(3);
    const speed = fetchSpeed(60, 200);
    const driver = fetchDriver();
    const first = driver.name.first;
    const last = driver.name.last;
    fetchedCars.push({
        licenseNumber,
        first,
        last,
        phoneNumber,
        geoPosition,
        speed,
        favorite: false,
        more: false,
    });
} while (fetchedCars.length < 20);
```

But `console.log(data)` in some cases still shows the value of undefined and I just don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score -1):

random user API has a rate limiter. use this to fetch multiple users in one request (for example 20 users):

> https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20

check the documentation [here](https://randomuser.me/documentation#multiple)

[This](https://github.com/RandomAPI/Randomuser.me-Node/issues/100#issuecomment-386390402) GitHub thread mentions the rate-limiting and the solution I've included

Comment: @BartoszKról was this answer helpful?